# Java IP validation RegEx with wildcard *

Tags: java, regex, spring, regex-group

I'm trying to make my own Regex to match IP along with * wildcard
my own regex for now is :

**^((((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\*){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){1,3}\*))$**

but it's not working as I wish,
I want to give regex given this conditions Ex.:

192.168.1.1 --> valid

192.168.1.* --> valid

192.168.*.* --> valid

192.*.*.* --> valid

---

192.168.*.1 --> invalid

192.*.1.1 --> invalid

192.*.*.1 --> invalid

*.168.1.1 --> invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use a positive lookahead to assert for 3 following dots with either 3 digits or a `*`

When matching you could make the `*` the last part and optional.

```
^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(?=(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|\*)){3}$)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))*(?:\.\*)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WvNVRz/1)

Another option is to spell out all the alternatives:

```
^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.\*|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.\*\.\*|\*\.\*\.\*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iD6nhx/1)

Comment: @Springmailer I have updated the pattern with the ranges.

Comment: By the way the Ip number pattern is still somehow invalid since allow like `01`. So leading zeroes.

Comment: @Eraklon You are right, I have updated it with a slightly more restrictive pattern.

Comment: Oh and you could make it somewhat shorter/more readable by replacing `[0-9]` with `\d`.